# Stop people getting my ip from my domain name.?

Tags: server, vpn, mask, minecraft, ddos

1st of all YES my domain name is pointed at my ip no hate.
The reason that is because i have a minecraft server + teamspeak server + Webserver.

NOW, i released a minecraft server 2 days ago, on the 1st day i got taken down from DDOS Attacks, Due to people pulling my ip from the Domain name AKA Host to IP.
Is there anyone to create a fake ip that people get from host to ip.
Ask Lets say my ip is: 1.2.3.4
and my domain name is: blabla.com
and people do the host to ip it will show the wrong ip such as: 2.4.6.8.
Is that possible?

Comment: You can serve up any IP you want via DNS, but exactly how do you plan to tell the difference between "do DNS lookup to visit site" and "do DNS lookup to attack site"? And in any case, offtopic - not a programming questions. We are not general networking/server/DNS tech support.

Comment: No, not possible. The user machines must be able to lookup your IP in order to allow incoming connections. The same allows for DDOS attackers to perform same lookup.

Comment: This just isn't possible. Your browser, minecraft client, teamspeak client, etc have to know which IP to point to. That is held on the DNS servers. If you tell them a different IP, then the clients can't connect. A domain name is simply an alias for your IP. It's worthless without it. - Lastly there is no hate to give. You point your Domain name at your IP. That's how it works. Perhaps consider CloudFlare or similar to keep some of the riff raff at bay.

Comment: If you have multiple ips / servers it's possible; regardless, this question is not related to programming as stated — good luck.

Answer (score 5):

The sole purpose of the domain name service is to point to IP addresses so there is no way around that. You can use one of the dynamic IP services to change your IP but then you lose the advantage of having a static ip